# How to add a Django app to settings.py app_name or app_name.apps.AppNameConfig?

Tags: django, django-apps

I have seen that there are two ways to add a Django app to the `settings`. Assuming the app is `app_name`, I've seen the following patters:

1. Using `app_name`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # other apps
    'app_name'
]
```

2. Using `app_name.apps.AppNameConfig`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # other apps
    'app_name.apps.AppNameConfig'
]
```

I am wondering if there is any difference between these two patterns or if they are equivalent. I also wonder if there is any preferred way to add an application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are somehow equivalent, with the exception that the `AppConfig` offer a way to customise app's metadata (and maybe more in the future).

This enables you to "rename" 3rd party apps into something else in your project, so it does not collide with a custom app written by you, for example.

There is no preferred way, but from my experience - make an `AppConfig`.

More on this in [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS) and [AppConfig docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/).